# Opening a new tab using datalist

Tags: javascript, html, select, datalist

I am trying to create a link from the datalist that will open in new tab or window with a click of another Go button.

I saw a similar script but only applicable for Select:

```
<select name="choice" id="choice">
    <option value="http://publish.samsungsimulator.com/simulator/1fca0505-cf2e-4f42-ac96-e1cf1ed7b65a/">Samsung Galaxy S9</option>
    <option value="http://publish.samsungsimulator.com/simulator/5279d684-ff3f-4aae-97a6-ecf8e79015d9/">Samsung Galaxy S9+</option>
    <option value="http://publish.samsungsimulator.com/simulator/2c80206c-042a-4e90-9594-6bd72a8bd3bf/">Samsung Galaxy Note 9</option>
</select>
    <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="Go"   onclick="go_to_the_link()"/>
<script>
function go_to_the_link(){
    var element = document.getElementById("choice");
    var link = element.value;
    myWindow = window.open(link,"_blank");
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to apply this in datalist using a different JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: You mean by using input with <datalist> tag of html?

Comment: Yes, something like this: <datalist name="choice" id="choice">
    <option value="http://publish.samsungsimulator.com/simulator/1fca0505-cf2e-4f42-ac96-e1cf1ed7b65a/">Samsung Galaxy S9</option>
    <option value="http://publish.samsungsimulator.com/simulator/5279d684-ff3f-4aae-97a6-ecf8e79015d9/">Samsung Galaxy S9+</option>
    <option value="http://publish.samsungsimulator.com/simulator/2c80206c-042a-4e90-9594-6bd72a8bd3bf/">Samsung Galaxy Note 9</option>
</datalist>

Answer (score 0):

To open a link in a new tab you can use this function. Note: it only works after interaction ( like click ) not on page load

```
cons samsungSelect = document.getElementById('choice')

function openLinkInNewTag() {
  let aTag = document.createElement("a")
  aTag.href = samsungSelect.value
  aTag.target = "_blank"
  document.body.appendChild(aTag)
  aTag.click()
  document.body.removeChild(aTag)
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/zexLMd

Comment: Thank you. But I tried this and it didn't work using the following `code`:
 
<datalist name="choice" id="choice">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
</datalist>

<script>
function openLinkInNewTag() {
  let aTag = document.createElement("a")
  aTag.src = "url"
  aTag.target = "_blank"
  document.body.appendChild(aTag)
  aTag.click()
  document.parent.removeChild(aTag)
}
</script>

Comment: Thank you @Philipp, I appreciate your replies. It indeed wotk on <select>, but can we use and apply it on <datalist> tag? Thanks